# Is there a way to bound the variances estimates in the `coxme` R package?

Tags: r, mixed-models, survival-analysis, survival

I use the variance estimates obtained in a `coxme`output for a further procedure:

```
model = coxme(Surv(time, status) ~ (0 + A | B ) + (1| B ) + strata(A) , data)
NUM = sum(unlist(model$vcoef))
```

However, I need the sum of the two variances estimates (`NUM` in the example above) to be above 0.01.

**Is there any way to add bounds/condition for the variance estimates in the `coxme` function?**

I thought I could do something in the `control` argument by setting `optpar = list(method = "L-BFGS-B", lower=0.005)` but I just got errors or strange results.

Thanks in advance for your help!